# In Python: join df_1 and df_2 (one key column, 1:1 relationship) to create df_3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

In Python, I have a dataframe (df_1) with 1000 rows and 18 columns. I also have a separate dataframe (df_2) with 1000 rows and 18 columns. In both of these dataframes, I have only 1 key column, and the data is 1:1.

When I try

```
df_3 = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on="key_column", how ='outer')
df_3.info()
```

I get

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2000 entries, 0 to 1999
Data columns (total 35 columns):
```

The first 1000 rows are for df_1 (with null values in the columns from df_2), and the next 1000 rows are for df_2 (with null values in the columns from df_1).

What I really want are 1000 rows total and 35 columns, with all of the values from df_1 and df_2 (assuming few null values) included in df_3.

I'm not sure what I need to change to do this. I have tried left, inner, and right joins, but those clearly don't work.

Comment: What is the output of `df_1['key_column'].dtype` and `df_2['key_column'].dtype`? If they're different, you'll need to convert one of them to match the other.

Comment: The key columns have the same name. I don't know if this matters (I don't *think* it would, but I could certainly be wrong here), but df_1 included full_name as a column, where df_2 included first_name and last_name as two separate columns. I concatenated these two columns in df_2 to add full_name as a column, so that each dataframe would have a key column.

Comment: Got it, in that case, I'd suggest manually looking at specific values from each key column which you expect to be equal, and check what is making them distinct. Extra whitespace may have snuck in through the column concatenation, or maybe there are capitalization differences?

Comment: All of the other columns are unique to each dataframe, however. It is like df_1 has full_name, A, B, C--and df_2 has first_name, last_name, full_name, D, E, F. I want it to read full_name, first_name, last_name, A, B, C, D, E, F (order is for illustrative purposes only).

Comment: The odd thing is that I'm taking in 18 columns from df_1 and 18 columns from df_2, and it's giving me back 35 columns, so it's accepting it as a key column.

Comment: This shows more about what I mean:                                                                             `#   Column                              Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                              --------------  -----         
 0   CUSTOMER_NAME                       2000 non-null   object        
 1   SALE                                1000 non-null   float64  ` @PeterLeimbigler

Comment: If they're 1:1, why not [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them? `pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)`

Comment: Doing that returns 36 columns, and they aren't matched up. I get two full_name columns returned with different names in them. @RJAdriaansen

Comment: Sort both by `key_column` before concatenating, then drop one `full_name` column afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will work. (I had been thinking there could be a more succinct way of doing this, but I can't seem to find one!) @RJAdriaansen

Comment: Ugh, I just noticed that there are some misspelled names, and that is the only possible key data column that I have.